# Stuck with slider script. How do I properly design slider function?

Tags: javascript, html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgb(85, 175, 198);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 24% auto;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

#selector {
  height: 104px;
  width: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.SelectBtn {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  background-image: url(pee.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#SelectValue {
  width: 48px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgb(185, 193, 47);
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#SelectValue::after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 15px solid rgb(185, 193, 47);
  border-left: 24px solid rgb(85, 175, 198);
  border-right: 24px solid rgb(85, 175, 198);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 0;
}

#progressbar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 7px;
  background: rgb(141, 181, 26);
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

.question-container {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-title {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="question-container">
    <h1 class="main-title ng-binding">How many times a day do you urinate?</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="slider">
    <div id="selector">
      <div class="SelectBtn"></div>
      <div id="SelectValue"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    var selector = document.getElementById("selector");
    var SelectValue = document.getElementById("SelectValue");
    var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressbar");

    SelectValue.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      SelectValue.innerHTML = this.value;
      selector.style.left = this.value + "%"
      progressbar.style.width = this.value + "%"

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I wanted to make a slider where viewers can choose an integer between 0 and 10 but it does not work, the selector moves to the left end immediately after I click the button. (after I changed the max of input from 100 to 10, before that it worked fine)
I think the slider function at the bottom should be changed, but I still do not understand how to fix this.

Comment: where is the button?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click the button? There is no event listener on it.

Comment: @Aleksandar the button is selector

Comment: @Kielstra u can move the button. just like the basic movement of slider.

Comment: @hased Can you add the code that is supposed to run when you move the button? Currently the only code in here is when you change the value of the slider. Could you also add your CSS to the code snippet for a better reproduction?

Comment: @KielstraI am a super noob here so sorry for any dumb things XD.
Did I post the css as u said?

Comment: @Kielstra slider and the button are overlapped. What do you mean by 'too close'?

Comment: @hased No problem, for the next time: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet. Since your CSS was missing and based on your description the solution I proposed wasn't actually doing anything for you, so I removed it. Now the CSS is there it's clear the issue is probably with that. See the answer from Leonardum, it's looks very useful to me.

Comment: @Kielstra thanks to you sir/ma'am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentages have a range of 100... Just had to multiply your values by 10 to fix the range.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgb(85, 175, 198);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 24% auto;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

#selector {
  height: 104px;
  width: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.SelectBtn {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  background-image: url(pee.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#SelectValue {
  width: 48px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgb(185, 193, 47);
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#SelectValue::after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 15px solid rgb(185, 193, 47);
  border-left: 24px solid rgb(85, 175, 198);
  border-right: 24px solid rgb(85, 175, 198);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 0;
}

#progressbar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 7px;
  background: rgb(141, 181, 26);
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

.question-container {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-title {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="question-container">
    <h1 class="main-title ng-binding">How many times a day do you urinate?</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="slider">
    <div id="selector">
      <div class="SelectBtn"></div>
      <div id="SelectValue"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    var selector = document.getElementById("selector");
    var SelectValue = document.getElementById("SelectValue");
    var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressbar");

    SelectValue.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      SelectValue.innerHTML = this.value;
      selector.style.left = this.value*10 + "%"
      progressbar.style.width = this.value*10 + "%"

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @hased Do accept the answer and close it if it cleared your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things going wrong I believe.

The first one being that with the current styling, the user cannot properly access the slider, as it is covered by the 'selector' and 'progressbar' divs. I am not sure if there is a proper way to add a progress bar like the one you have in mind to a slider without running into this issue. You should, however, be able to make the selector div not cover the slider. Also, instead of having the 'SelectBtn', you could probably adjust the styling of the slider thumb. You can find an excellent article about that here: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/.

Lastly, regarding the adjustment of the position of your 'selector' and 'progressbar' by the js, this is due to your change from 100 to 10. Your js is basically giving a position / width to these elements based on the value of your slider. So when the value is 10, the width of the progress bar will be 10%. You need to multiply these by 10. I would advise something like this:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
    SelectValue.innerHTML = this.value;
    selector.style.left = `${10*this.value}%`;
    progressbar.style.width = `${10*this.value}%`;
}
```

Hope this will help you along!